# DOTNET first project commands

Tags: .net

I'm newbie in .NET and I dont understand the different between commands `dotnet new web` , `dotnet new webapi`,`dotnet new mvc` and `dotnet new page`.

I think it may be the type of templating of each one.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your guess about it being the template is correct - Take a look at the documentation for [dotnet new <TEMPLATE>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're templates.

**dotnet new web:**

This command creates a new web application project using the ASP.NET Core framework.
It's a general template for creating web applications and gives you a basic setup to start building your application.
This template is suitable for scenarios where you need a flexible starting point for your web project without any specific architectural pattern enforced.

**dotnet new webapi:**

This command creates a new ASP.NET Core Web API project.
Web APIs are specifically designed for building HTTP services that can be consumed by various clients like web applications, mobile apps, etc.
This template sets up your project to handle HTTP requests and responses, typically following RESTful principles.
It's suitable for scenarios where you need to create backend services to serve data to clients.

**dotnet new mvc:**

This command creates a new ASP.NET Core MVC (Model-View-Controller) project.
MVC is a design pattern that separates an application into three main components: Model (for data), View (for presentation), and Controller (for handling requests and responses).
This template sets up your project with the MVC architectural pattern, providing folders for Models, Views, and Controllers.
It's suitable for scenarios where you need to build a web application with server-side rendering and structured separation of concerns.

**dotnet new page:**

This command is not a standard template command in .NET Core or .NET 5 and later. However, it might be related to certain project structures or frameworks specific to your development environment or tools.
Without additional context, it's challenging to precisely define what dotnet new page would do. It could be a custom template or part of some other tooling you're using in your project.